# New column in the data.frame not getting the name assigned to it in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to `scale` my `data` and add it to my original data with a new name. I was wondering though why my scaled data does not get the new name assigned to it?

Here is what I tried:

```
    data <- mtcars["wt"]
    d <- scale(data)
    data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- d
    data
                    wt           wt   ## HERE 2nd column name has not changed I expect it to be "wt.bbb"
Mazda RX4        2.620   -0.610399567
Mazda RX4 Wag    2.875   -0.349785269
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `d` is a matrix with a column already having a name, and it happens that this name wins. Few minimal changes to your approach to fix that would be:

```
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- d[, 1]
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- as.numeric(d)
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- as.vector(d)
data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ] <- c(d)
```

Comment: In fact, if OP passed at least two columns, `data <- mtcars[c("wt", "qsec")]`, no change is needed!

Comment: Just curious, what if `data` in OP's question was this: `data <- mtcars[,2]`?

Comment: @morouzian, then `data` would be a vector, not a matrix, and the problem would be in writing `data[, paste0(names(data), ".bbb") ]`, which assumes two dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps something like: `data <- mtcars[,2] ;
data <- as.data.frame(data);
d <- as.data.frame(scale(data));
data[, paste0(names(d), ".bbb") ] <- d;
data`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
df <- mtcars
df$wt.bbb <- scale(df$wt)
```

Comment: OP likely wants to dynamically assign column names across any or many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Go take a look at ?scale() - you'll see that what you return is not just a vector of numbers, but actually a matrix. Therefore, you'll need a little more noodling to get what you want.

```
data <- mtcars["wt"]
scaled_matrix <- scale(data)
class(scaled_matrix)
scaled_values <- scaled_matrix[1:32]
class(scaled_values)
```

dplyr version

```
data %>% 
  mutate(your_name_here = d)
```

non-dplyr version

```
df <- cbind(data, "your_name_here" = scaled_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering though why my scaled data does not get the new name assigned to it?

It is because

```
class(d)
#R> [1] "matrix"
colnames(d)
#R> [1] "wt"
```

Thus, you could do

```
data <- mtcars["wt"]
data[paste0(names(data), ".bbb")] <- unname(scale(data))
data
#R>                       wt   wt.bbb
#R>Mazda RX4           2.620 -0.61040
#R>Mazda RX4 Wag       2.875 -0.34979
#R>Datsun 710          2.320 -0.91700
#R>Hornet 4 Drive      3.215 -0.00230
#C> [output abbreviated]
```

See `help("print.data.frame")` and call `format` with a matrix which has column names.